# Processing multiple values for one single option using getopt/optparse?

Tags: python, getopt

Is it possible to fetch multiple values for one option using getopt or optparse, as shown in the example below:

```
./hello_world -c arg1 arg2 arg3 -b arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7
```

Please note that the number of actual values for each option (-c, -b) could be either 1 or 100. I do not want to use:
`./hello_world -c "arg1 arg2 arg3" -b "arg4 arg5 arg6 arg7"`

It seems to me that this may not be possible (and perhaps in violation of POSIX), please correct me if I'm wrong.

I've seen examples where all the non-options at the end of the line (`./hello_world -c arg1 -b arg1 arg2 arg3`) can be gathered... but not for the first of multiple option.

I'd like my app to work on a wide range of platforms with different Python versions, so I've not looked at argparser.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it can be done with optparse.

This is an example:

```
./test.py --categories=aaa --categories=bbb --categories ccc arg1 arg2 arg3
```

which prints:

```
arguments: ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
options: {'categories': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']}
```

Full working example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys
from optparse import OptionParser
from optparse import Option, OptionValueError

VERSION = '0.9.4'

class MultipleOption(Option):
    ACTIONS = Option.ACTIONS + ("extend",)
    STORE_ACTIONS = Option.STORE_ACTIONS + ("extend",)
    TYPED_ACTIONS = Option.TYPED_ACTIONS + ("extend",)
    ALWAYS_TYPED_ACTIONS = Option.ALWAYS_TYPED_ACTIONS + ("extend",)

    def take_action(self, action, dest, opt, value, values, parser):
        if action == "extend":
            values.ensure_value(dest, []).append(value)
        else:
            Option.take_action(self, action, dest, opt, value, values, parser)


def main():
    PROG = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(__file__)[0])
    long_commands = ('categories')
    short_commands = {'cat':'categories'}
    description = """Just a test"""
    parser = OptionParser(option_class=MultipleOption,
                          usage='usage: %prog [OPTIONS] COMMAND [BLOG_FILE]',
                          version='%s %s' % (PROG, VERSION),
                          description=description)
    parser.add_option('-c', '--categories', 
                      action="extend", type="string",
                      dest='categories', 
                      metavar='CATEGORIES', 
                      help='comma separated list of post categories')

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        parser.parse_args(['--help'])

    OPTIONS, args = parser.parse_args()
    print "arguments:", args
    print "options:", OPTIONS

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

More information at http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#adding-new-actions

Answer (score 14):

Despite the claims of the other comments, this is possible with vanilla optparse, at least as of python 2.7. You just need to use action="append". From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html):

```
parser.add_option("-t", "--tracks", action="append", type="int")
```

If -t3 is seen on the command-line, optparse does the equivalent of:

```
options.tracks = []
options.tracks.append(int("3"))
```

If, a little later on, --tracks=4 is seen, it does:

```
options.tracks.append(int("4"))
```

Comment: This is a more conventional solution to the problem. Passing multiple arguments to a single flag is a misleading practice and has a high probability of causing problems down the line. If you need IFS separated words passed to an *option*, I'd encourage users to quote the value and then split it within your code. Otherwise, stick with command arguments or repeated flags as suggested in this answer.

Comment: This requires arguments to be passed as "-c arg1 -c arg2 -c arg3" not "-c arg1 arg2 arg3" like the question requested.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry to come late to the party but I just solved this with optparse using the nargs flag.

```
parser.add_option('-c','--categories', dest='Categories', nargs=4 )
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse.Option.nargs

It is also worth noting, that argparse (suggested by unutbu) is now part of the standard python distribution while optparse is deprecated.

Comment: Suppose if i wanted to put check here, if user has not input arguments. how to read 4 arguments into "option.Categories" one by one

Comment: Note that this limits you to 4 arguments for `-c`.

Comment: Following from @Plasma it also requires 4 arguments no more and no less.

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be to define a separator and process it locally, like the options in the mount command.

For example, if `,` can be used as a separator:

```
...
args, _ = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'b:')
for flag, arg in args:
  if flag=='-b': all_arguments = arg.split(',')
...

$ ./test -b opt1,opt2,opt3
```

Same for space! But then your users have to quote it properly.

```
$ ./test -b 'opt1 opt2 opt3'
```

Answer (score 6):

Neither getopt nor optparse support this out of the box. In addition, in the default (GNU) mode, the additional arguments would be treated as interspersed args, i.e. become available as left-over arguments at the end of the processing.

The convention would be to require repeated mentioning of the same argument, i.e.

```
./hello_world -c arg1 -c arg2 -c arg3 -b arg4 -b arg5 -b arg6 -b arg7
```

This is will supported.

If you absolutely want to get it work the way you specify (i.e. both -b and -c extend until the next - argument or the end of the argument list), then you can hack something together based on optparse. Inherit from OptionParser, and override _process_short_opts. If it's one of your options, process it in the subclass, else forward to the base class.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the convention. That was what I thought..
The issue is that the number of values for each option makes using that convention non-user-friendly. I think I'm likely to end up iterating through sys.argv and handling things on my own.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the `nargs` parameter in `argparse` which comes with Python2.7, and downloadable [here](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/).

I think it is one of the improvements added to `argparse` which is not in `optparse`. So, unfortunately, I don't think there is a nice way to handle this with `optparse` or `getopt` (which is even older).

A quick and dirty solution might be to forgo `optparse/getop/argparse` and just parse `sys.argv` yourself.

Or, going in the opposite direction, you might consider packaging a frozen copy of argparse (~88K) (renamed something like `argparse_static`) with your program, and
importing it like this:

```
try:
    import argparse
except ImportError:
    import argparse_static as argparse
```

That way, the program will use `argparse` if it is installed, and will use   `argparse_static` if it is not. Best of all, you won't have to rewrite much code as `argparse` becomes standard.

Comment: Thank you so much for two quick and in-depth answers. I did manage to write my own option parser that handles things. Downloading a static copy of argparse was not something that I've considered, but it's on the table now.

Comment: My vote is with argparse.  It is easier to get my head around than optparse was. (And I was one who hacked on optparse when it was Optik, before it made it into the standard library)

Answer (score 3):

An easier one:

```
make_option(
    "-c",
    "--city",
    dest="cities",
    action="append",
    default=[],
    help="specify cities",
)
```

[Append action](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#standard-option-actions) is the easiest solution for this problem.