# Python argparse with choices and nargs=2

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to create an option that takes two arguments. The first argument should be validated by choices, but the second argument is an arbitrary user-supplied value. For example.

```
> app -h
usage: app [--option {count,label} arg]
```

Correct usage examples:

```
> app --option count 1
> app --option count 912
> app --option label userfoo
```

I tried setting it up like this:

```
parser.add_argument('--option', choices=['count','label'], nargs=2)
```

This does not work, as it tries to validate BOTH arguments using the choices. The help string shows this:

```
usage: app [--option {count,label} {count,label}]
```

There are several ways I could do it manually:

- remove the choices field and manually validate the first argument in code.
- separate it into `--option count --value 3`, but that is awkward as --value is required by option but invalid without it. It is really a single option with two values
- make --option have a compound value, for example `--option count=3` and then parse the value

Part of what I want is to have the auto-generated help string show the choices for the first argument. I would also like for argparse to detect and report errors whenever possible with a minimum of custom code. The reason is that we have a very complex CLI, and this helps maintain consistency.

Is there a way to do this with argparse?

Comment: This SO question has a good discussion on how to do it an also why it might be bad to have multiple values for a single option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109436/processing-multiple-values-for-one-single-option-using-getopt-optparse/14824041

Comment: You could write a custom `type` function and/or `Action` class to handle this.  Or you could do the value testing after parsing.  But as you discovered `argparse` normally applies the same testing to all of the `nargs` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parser._get_values` does, when `nargs` is number:

```
        value = [self._get_value(action, v) for v in arg_strings]
        for v in value:
            self._check_value(action, v)
```

`_get_value` applies the `type` function, while `_check_value` test the `choices`.  After this the `values` list is passed to the `store` Action.

So the normal processing applies the same `type` and `choices` test to each string.

I can imagine writing a `type` function that accepts both numbers and strings from a list.  But it couldn't distinguish between the first and second arguments.  A custom `Action` will see both, and could do further testing.

But often it's simpler to just do your own value testing after parsing.  The `parser` doesn't have to do everything.  It's primary function is to figure out what the user wants.  Checking values and raising a standardized error is nice part of parsing, but isn't its primary purpose.

Also think about how you'd specify the usage/help for the expected input.